# Should you create a Foreign key table for Simple never changing data e.g. mathematical operations vs using descriptive text

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, foreign-keys

In my database I have a **Rule** table. The user in my application can build up a number of rules which can compare various fields e.g. **FieldA is greater than FieldB**. Greater than is not the only condition it can be replaced with equals, less than, in between etc.

This condition needs to be stored on my Rule table. I see two options, one is to include a column which has text to identify it. The data would look something like this.

```
Id,Name,FieldId,FieldToCompareId,Condition
1000,RuleA,2000,2001,GreaterThan
```

The second option would be to create a foreign key table with all these conditions in and having a FK on the rule table, something like this

```
ConditionTable            RuleTable
---------------           ----------
Id,ConditionName          Id,Name,FieldId,FieldToCompareId,ConditionId
1000,GreaterThan          1000,RuleA,2000,2001,1000
1001,Equals
```

The first option is the simplest and quickest way, one disadvantage being that the description of the condition can never change. The second option seems better if i were too add other columns that could change e.g. a descriptive name that would be shown to the user rather than working it out in my application based of the text.

My main issue for the second option is that I have many places that will follow this structure so I would end up creating lots of different tables for very static data and this also adds to the complexity of accessing the data in my application.

Is the first option a sensible solution or should I always be refactoring out a foreign key table so I am only storing Ids in the rows instead of text?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the second approach has always worked out for the best in the long run.  The pain is in the design, but then views can be created to simplify the data access logic.  Also, modern frameworks and designers have built in support for this design which makes creating user interfaces fairly simple.

If you opt for option 1, you can add other fields to avoid parsing text in your application layer.

In either case you can also take an approach similar to what I have done in the past.  I created a design that would actually store field names and operators in separate fields so that I could build dynamic sql queries to enforce the rules.  Greater than, equals, IN, NOT IN...

Answer (score 0):

I believe both of your options are too rigid to stand long term business need changes

There is a third option, which is not storing that information in the database but as application classes. This is the best in the long term if you do not have a requirement for allowing run-time update of the rules.

If the requirement for update of the rules exist then I would suggest to use a more generic approach where rules are still stored in application classes as templates and only the associations of the rule to target object for all such rule-binding is stored in a single table with columns like this:

RuleId int
RuleParameters    varchar
TargetObjectType  varchar
TargetObjectIdentier  varchar

Obviously, the rule parameters require some sort of parsing to associate the rule application parameters with the target object. And, the same goes for associating the target object using its type and identifier (which can be a compound key) But, still a viable option defending design integrity in the long-term

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

The right way answer your question is to consider the functional dependencies, to eliminate redundancy.  If you choose your first solution, what's to prevent adding a RuleB that's mathematically identical to RuleA?  Would that be a bad thing?  What if RuleA turns out to be incorrectly defined or misused?  What if you'd like to present the user with a distinct list of rules?  What if you'd like to summarize rule use, or prevent certain kinds of rules?

These questions suggest that, in your universe, a rule's definition is independent of its use in a condition.  For that reason, it should be identified independently (by name) and referenced by conditions.

> this also adds to the complexity of accessing the data in my application

Not necessarily.  Views were created for that very purpose.  You can reproduce your first solution from your second one with a single join.